# JQUERY UI Accordion Resize on Window Resize?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, accordion

I'm using the JQUERY UI Accordion module:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#sidebar_column_accordion").accordion({
        fillSpace: true,
        icons: { 'header': 'ui-icon-plus', 'headerSelected': 'ui-icon-minus' }
    });
});
</script>
```

By using the fillSpace option, the accordion takes up the entire height of the window which I want. Problem is it calculate the height on page load, and if the user resizes their browser, it does not adjust...

Is there a way to have the accordion recalculate the height/size when the browser window is resized?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $("#sidebar_column_accordion").accordion("resize");
});
```

In jQuery UI 1.9 the resize method was removed. The refresh method was added which is more robust and will work in this case also.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $("#sidebar_column_accordion").accordion("refresh");
});
```

Comment: That seems way to easy! I'll try that tonight and get back. thxs

Comment: Did you find this on a doc somewhere? I can't find this anywhere?

Comment: Doesn't look like the docs have it shown but the demo source shows the user of the resize method for the accordion. http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#fillspace

Comment: Thanks that worked incredibly. It's to bad they don't have that in the docs!

Comment: Starting to get a little annoyed with jQuery always deprecating everything, but in any case this only seems to work when making the window bigger, not smaller.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this has been updated to "refresh"

```
$(function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
heightStyle: "fill"
});
});
$(function() {
$( "#accordion-resizer" ).resizable({
minHeight: 140,
minWidth: 200,
resize: function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion( "refresh" );
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set autoHeight: 'content' in the accordion decalaration. This will make the div use the native height of the content:

```
$('#accordion').accordion({
    autoHeight: 'content'
});
```

See here for more info: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#no-auto-height

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions posted did not work for me, though they were close.

Define your accordion using heightStyle:fill, like so:

```
$("#sidebar_column_accordion").accordion({
                  heightStyle: "fill"
                });
```

Create a function to calculate and set the height.  Note that I had to do both, set the height and then call refresh on the accordion.  One won't work without the other.

```
function calculateHeight(){
  var height = $('#maincontent').height();  // Or whatever height you want
  $('#sidebar_column_accordion').height(height);
  $('#sidebar_column_accordion').accordion("refresh");
}
```

Call this function on both page load and window resize.

```
calculateHeight();

$(window).resize(function () {
  calculateHeight();
});
```